# Download video data as blob from Dropbox via JS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, dropbox

I'm trying to automatically generate thumbnails for videos that have been uploaded to my Dropbox via Zoom. I'm using fluent-ffmpeg in a Firebase function, so the environment is a node.js runtime. I can get the Dropbox share url of the video when it loads, but I can't figure out how to download the file into the node environment as a blob so that ffmpeg can process it and generate the screenshots.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Multer, upload the files and read them through FFMPEG and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js), you can use [the `filesDownload` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload__anchor) to download a file directly, or [the `sharingGetSharedLinkFile` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingGetSharedLinkFile__anchor) to download a file from a shared link.

There's [an example of handling the result in Node here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/javascript/node/download.js). (That happens to be written for `sharingGetSharedLinkFile`, but `filesDownload` works the same way.)